# How to apply saturn's ring texture in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: textures, unreal-4, blender, 3d-meshes, unreal

I'm working on a "solar system" model project. And while trying to apply saturn's ring texture which is this one : 
[image]

it ended up looking like this:
[image]

I'm new to UE4 and this branch in general. So I have no idea how to fix this . 
your help would be appreciated

Comment: How did you make the ring model? Are you familiar with UV unwrapping?

Comment: I made a new static mesh by putting one cylinder inside of another and setting its brush type to substactive and no I'm not familiar with it :(

Comment: I tried making the ring but putting a sphere inside of another one , appilied the material but didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the best result for your project, there is basically two ways:

- Make your own 3D models from scratch with a 3D software like **[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)** (free)/ **[Maya LT](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya-lt/overview?plc=MAYALT&term=1-YEAR&support=ADVANCED&quantity=1)**/ **[3DS Max](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview)**.
- download free 3D models from various websites (I personally do not rely on this solution so I don't know if these websites will be good, but you can always download models from **Clara.io** or **CGTrader**).

If you want to make the 3D Model from scratch, you will need to model the Rings of Saturn and **unwrap** the **[UVs](https://conceptartempire.com/uv-mapping-unwrapping/)** (that's the main problem in your result), and either create the texture from scratch (with **Blender**, **Substance** or another Texture Software) or apply the texture that you've uploaded here.

Please note that your current texture of the Rings of Saturn will be displayed in *Unreal Engine*, but it is definitely not the right format in the gaming industry (i.e., the resolution of your file is not a **[Power of Two](https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/textures/make-better-textures-correct-size-and-power-of-two.php)** like **256*256** or **1024*1024**). The various reasons of keeping a Power of Two texture might not ring a bell at this stage but should be kept in mind (mip-maps, no GPU optimization, no multi-plaform game support...).

If Blender will be your choice for the 3D Software (and Texture Software), you can watch some YouTube tutorials for beginners, like **[Blender Guru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4)** or [**Grant Abbitt**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MRonzqYJgw&list=PLn3ukorJv4vs_eSJUQPxBRaDS8PrVmIri).

Good luck with your Solar System project!

Comment: Thank u for your reply ^^ I'm still confused with something . So what I have to do is make the ring mesh in blender , apply texture to it , adjust the texture and then unwrap it and import it to ue4? or do I have to import the whole ring along with the texture ?

Comment: You're welcome! If you're using Blender, you will have to model the Ring Mesh, import & apply the existing texture, unwrap the UV and match it to the texture, export (from Blender) in FBX and then import the whole file in Unreal, along with the texture.